# Apple in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test my in-app purchase on my book collection app. I'm using mag+ publish tool for this, maybe someone know it.

I put downloadable content files in my server and upload them correctly (my free issue download is ok). I set my in-app purchase in iTunes connect and I activate it with "cleared for sale yes". I create my test user id, sign out in settings open my app and push the button to buy my issue. The message "are you sure to buy nameofmyissue?" appears, and I put my id and password. The App Store opens after I check ok, but I got this message `[environment: sandbox]` and the download never starts.

Is that the expected behaviour, or there is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[environment: sandbox] is development side so may be it cause not download

and I think in production(distribution) mode it will run fine

Thanks hope this two line helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Settings > iTunes & App Store
2) Tap on the Apple ID and delete the entry
3) Tap Done

This should cause this section to display a Sign In message now.

Now try to make the In-App Purchase again.  You should be prompted to sign in to the App Store before proceeding.  Then it'll ask you to enter your password again to make the actual purchase.

(AFAIK once the product(which you want to sell as part of IAP) on the iTunes store is approved, the message of sandbox will be removed. This will be done when you put your application for approval process. User will automatically diverted for actual product and not the sand box one.)